# count total no of visits based on date codeigniter

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

Аctually I am working on the CI medical project. I have column name `visit date`. I want to display the total no of visits by each patient on that specific date, for example `5-4-2019` total visits by that patient were `3`. Similarly `4-3-2020` total visits were `5`.

[image: you can see in the picture i have column name with visit_date]

How can I create another column that counts total visits based on this column `visit date`?

Comment: I would suggest you to use another mapping table including `user _id` and `count` without including `count` to the same table.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have provided no DDL or DML, the best we can do is guess at what your schema might be and what your code might look like. So, here's a guess:

```sql
select   -- <your existing columns>
         visits_on_this_date = count(*) over (partition by patient_id, visit_date)
from     -- the rest of your query here
```

Comment: cau you write this query in CI formate syntax ... ??

Answer (score 0):

Something simple like that?

```
select patient_id,visit_date,count(*) as total_visits
from table
group by patient_id,visit_date
```

Comment: thanks for the answer actually i want is to create another column by checking dates for example right now i have no column named as total_visits , but i have column visit date .. i want is that if i visit to doctor for 3 times at the same date , then i will create another column named as total_visits and set the 3 mean 3 total visits

Comment: @MujtabaHussain total visits of the specific patient on a specific date?Or in general? I'm confused. If you want the first one, that's what count(*) gives you

Comment: ok well i will try this query and will let you know ... visits_date (2-3-2019) .... total_visits(5) .. something like this

Comment: thats what brings you my query. For every customer,every date,how many visits